# How can I delete all .LNK files on my Ubuntu machine?

Tags: command-line, wine, files, microsoft-office

For some reason, when I launch Office 2010 using WINE, it creates a lnk file in the Recent directory of my Windows Profile.

I just checked the folder and there were ~2000 LNK files.

How would I delete all LNK files on system startup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find [path] -iname '*.LNK'
```

If you run the above and are fine with deleting all of the listed files, then:

```
find [path] -iname '*.LNK' -print -delete
```

You can leave out `-print` if you don't care to see which files are being deleted.

With `-iname` it's case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

For a permanent solution I suggest to manually create the "Recent" folder in your PlayOnLinux / Wine installation:

PlayOnLinux:

```
~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Office2010/drive_c/users/YourUserName/Recent
```

Wine:

```
~/.wine/drive_c/users/YourUserName/Recent
```

I hope it helps!